# White text under buttons in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a lay-out on my android project that involves buttons. Earlier I had the name of the button inside the button itself. Now I have icons inside them, but I need to name them as well now. I want to do that under the buttons, but because of my background, I think i have to do it in white letters. I have no Idea where to program the letters, and how to make them white. Does anyone of you know how?

In the image that I added below, you can see 2 forms of layouts. The left one is the one I currently have. The right one is a design from a while ago. You can see the white text under each button. That white text is what I want under my buttons now.

[image]

This is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/rkzafbeelding">


   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/logoversiejuni" />

 </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bezoektijdenbutton"
            android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

          <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/contactbutton"
            android:text="  Contact" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/routebutton"
            android:text="Route" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/meningbutton"
            android:text="Uw mening" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/vriendenbutton"
            android:text="Word vriend" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/foldersbutton"
            android:text="Folders" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/specialistenbutton"
            android:text="Specialisten" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bwcbutton"
            android:text="Brandwond  encentrum" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/nieuwsbutton"
            android:text="Nieuws en Agenda" />
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Every help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap every `ImageButton`in a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton ... />

    <TextView
        ...
        android:text="your title here"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is that you can use button for this and set it's **drawableTop** for setting images and use **textColor** for setting text color.

Otherwise for changing in your xml you can use **LinearLayout** with orientation **vertical** and **two child** one is your existing **ImageButton** and another is **TextView**.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is creating your own button item using imageView and TextView inside RelativeLayout.

**button_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        tools:text="ButtonText" />


</LinearLayout>
```